# umlgraph error, Could not find the main class

Tags: java, uml

Folks, trying to automatically generate UML diagrams from code to speed up the discovery process.  I've come across a project that does exactly what we need, http://www.umlgraph.org/doc/indexw.html

After the installation, I get the following:

```
umlgraph test png
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:   org/umlgraph/doclet/UmlGraph : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraph. Program will exit.
```

Java version on the system:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11.90) (rhel-1.62.1.11.11.90.el6_4-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Can someone please point me in the correct direction? Does anyone use a similar project? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like umlgraph 5.6_6.1-SNAPSHOT was compiled for Java 7 only. Here's a snapshot from it's build.xml:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" debug="true" deprecation="true" >
    <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
</javac>
```

No "target" attribute set explicitly, so platform java version is used. And from JAR manifest it's obvoius, that it was compiled on java 1.7

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2 
Created-By:  1.7.0_21-b11 (Oracle Corporation)
```

So you can either install Java 7 to run umlgraph, or use the older version of ulmgraph, which was compiled to be compartible with Java 6.